# Second menu on mobile

Tags: mobile, menu, responsive-design, mobile-web

I have a secondary nav which is related to the content on the current page as opposed to the primary nav which is a global menu. What is the best way to have two menus on mobile. Both have to be preferably at the top unless you have a strong reasoning otherwise.

Here is an idea/suggestion that I have, but feel free to suggest something completely different. The primary menu in the image below is sparse but it will have more links. Is it okay to have the secondary menu in a dropdown like the primary?

On desktop
[image: On Desktop]

On mobile menu colapsed
[image: On mobile]

on mobile menu opened
[image: On mobile open]

Answer (score 2):

I'd first question whether you need global navigation on mobile. I'm often asked to implement global navigation on projects because project leads have a belief that users want to 'hand out' in the application and be able to navigate from one point to any other point.

But in terms of actual usage, that's not now most people interact with most applications--at least on mobile. A hub-and-spoke model of navigation tends to work a lot better. If they want to navigate somewhere else, a tap on 'back' or 'home' to get to the main navigation is typically preferred for a couple of reasons:

- navigating 'back' or 'up' on a mobile device tends to be rather trivial (tap or swipe)
- it frees up valuable real-estate on the task-driven pages--which are typically the primary objective of the user.
- on a lot of mobile apps, people want to come in, finish a task, and be done. They don't *need* to navigate freely from any one page to another.

Looking at your sample images, I'm not entirely clear what you consider to be the main vs. secondary navigation. They also appear to be wide pages (so not sure I understand the mobile-centric part).

That said, consider the many different ways to present navigation on a mobile device...swipe-to-show-nav-beneath, footer icons, swipe-to-open panels, etc.

UPDATE:

Based on your comments, here's one suggestion. This removes the global menu for a 'hub and spoke' model (back) and the activate menu moved to the title bar:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f734tn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: What did u not understand

Comment: @aWebDeveloper you tell me

Comment: plz see the updated question and let me know if this makes it clear

Comment: @aWebDeveloper based on my understanding of what you are asking, I stand behind my answer. In general, you don't want to menus on the top of your mobile app.

Comment: i was asking about where to place sub menu

Comment: @aWebDeveloper maybe I'm not being very clear. Sorry. My suggestion is to consider *not* having a sub menu. Get rid of the main menu so you only have to deal with the menu for this particular page.

Comment: lets say i only show title in the title bar. How do you want me to show the second menu

Comment: @eWebDeveloper I updated the answer with one possible solution.